# Combination on the different sum of money

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many different sums of money can be made from penny, a nickel (5 pennies), a dime (10 pennies) and a quarter (25 pennies)?

I am having trouble sorting out the answer. As far as I have made progress, my answer would be $\binom{4}{2}$, but I still have doubts.

Comment: How did you get $4C2$? Do you need to use exactly two of the coins?

Comment: I dont know sir. I dont understand the question itself. Can you please explain it to me sir?

Comment: In my textbook the problem was solved -4C1 + 4C2 + 4C3 +4C4. Can i know how it is done?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following, when we only consider the penny and nickel: I could not put in the penny and get $0$ cents, or put in the penny and get $1$ cent, and I could add or not add the nickel, and get $0$ or $5$ cents. We'd like to automatically count the money added for these different choices, so consider the product $$(1+x)(1+x^{5})=1+x+x^{5}+x^{6}.$$ Each of the possible amounts of money is one term on the right hand side, and arises as a particular choice of adding/not adding the penny and similarly for the nickel, which correspond to the $1$ or $x$ in $(1+x)$ (the penny) or the $1$ or $x^{5}$ in $(1+x^{5})$ (the nickel).

Then the number we want is just the count of the number of different terms that appear in $$(1+x)(1+x^{5})(1+x^{10})(1+x^{25})$$ after expanding. This approach generalizes well to the case where we have, say, $5$ pennies, $3$ nickels, $2$ dimes, and a quarter: we would consider $(1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+x^{4}+x^{5})(1+x^{5}+x^{10}+x^{15})\cdots$ (Exercise: Figure out the other two factors).

Another way to approach this is to recognize that there are no two ways to arrive at the same amount of money, for this set of coins (which might require enumerating them, but could be deduced because no coin's value equals the sum of some other set of coins' values). Then since each coin can be included or not included, there are $2$ choices for whether or not the penny is in, and for each of these, there are $2$ choices for whether or not the nickel is in, and so forth, giving $$2\times 2\times 2\times 2=2^{4}.$$ This gives the same answer as the method above, as we would expect.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, a nickel = $5$ pennies, a dime = $10$ pennies and a quarter = $25$ pennies. Since we have only one from each of them, we have $4$ coins in total. Now notice that whichever zero,one, two, three or four of them we choose, the sum will be unique (Because there is no pair of coins such that when you sum them, the result is the value of another coin). Therefore, the answer is 
$$\binom{4}{0}+\binom{4}{1}+\binom{4}{2}+\binom{4}{3}+\binom{4}{4} = 2^4 = 16$$

Comment: So, you either **take** the coin or **not**. And the decision is independent on other coins !

Comment: Yes actually, exactly. But this is the case only because each sum is unique. Otherwise we would be overcounting.