# How many distinct amounts of money can be made from any combination of 1 quarter, 3 dimes, and 1 nickel?

Tags: combinatorics

I saw from these problems [Combination on the different sum of money](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2591195/combination-on-the-different-sum-of-money) that you would rely on the fact that they couldn't sum together. With more coins they can sum together. Is there a work around other than listing them?

Comment: Note that in the answer by RideTheWavelet that uses generating functions, you can still count the terms, ignoring their coefficients (which were all $1$ in that case and won't all be $1$ in your case).